# How to: External Monitor (HDMI)

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, displayport

I'm on a Dell xps l502x 64 dual boot machine.

It worked on both, but I had a accident: the screen cracked, so after that I tried to use an external HDMI display as primary display. Now it only works on ubuntu 14 but since I had an HDMI audio issue I unplugged (and replugged) the display and it doesn't get detected anymore. I tried a little research and couldn't find anything so I did a update and the laptop re-booted but NOW can't get any display on the external HDMI Monitor (an LG TV).

I already tried the `Fn+f1` key but it doesn't work anymore. I therefore tried the `Fn+"1-0"` key, but no luck.

I was wondering if there's another `Fn` Enable/Disable way or command to Auto Use Hdmi port. I tried `xrandr` commands without luck. Then again, I have no clear display, it's just blind guessing. It would be nice to be able to use an HDMI Monitor on Boot/BIOS.

Thought I mention after Screen cracked everything still was running good as it was only Little problems like no more Monitor in Windows7 and Audio-Output w/ HDMI  sound on laptop works tho process and GPU STILL good

Comment: The language in your post was a bit hard to understand, so I tried to edit it. If I missed (or mis-represented) one of your points, feel free to correct again.